# Кавычки в источнике цитаты

Tags: пунктуация, оформление-текста

В тексте приводится абзац из другого произведения, а в конце указан источник. Нужно ли название цитируемого произведения заключать в кавычки в подписи?

1. И. О. Фамилия. «Название книги»
2. И. О. Фамилия. Название книги

Answer (score 2):

Не вдаваясь в подробности, приведу пример подписи к цитированному из журнала тексту. Для источников книжных указывают название издательств.

*Холодная, М.А. Когнитивный стиль как квадриполярное измерение / М.А. Холодная // Психологический журнал. – 2000. – № 4. – С. 45–56.*

Правила цитирования допускают «ненаучный» подход к цитированию. Выделение кавычками названия источника и здесь не является нормой:

«Великая цель всякого человеческого существа — осознать любовь.» *(Пауло Коэльо. Одиннадцать минут)*.